# Find an element in an array with limited comparisons?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Given X, M, N where X = element to be searched in an array and N = access only first N elements in an array and M = array size, how do we find an element in an array with maximum (N+1) comparisons?

For example, 
A = [3,5,2,9,8,4,1,6,7] here M = 9
Let's have N = 6 and X = 5 => So for this case, access only first 6 elements of an array and try to find whether X is present in it or not? Here answer will return true. But for X = 6 answer will be false.

This problem is not about time complexity. it's about number of comparisons you make.  For example, Brute force method looks like this.

```
    void search(vector<int> A){
               for(int i=0; i<N; i++){ // [i < N is also comparison which is N times]
                     if(A[i] != X) continue;              // [N comparisons ]
                     else return true;
               }
               return false;
     }
```

Time complexity is  O(n) but number of comparisons will be 2*N. Reduce this comparisons to (N+1). I tried to solve it but did not get solution. Is there any solution actually for this?

Comment: Does `X`, `N`, `M` known at compile time ?

Answer (score 1):

## Idea

Modify N+1-th element to have X value and eliminate range check. Then once you have found element with X value (which is going to be true if M < N), check it's index (this is a last check that you can perform). If it's equal to N+1 then you haven't found one.

## Analysis

Despite that the approach eliminates comparisons duplication, it's still has one "extra" comparison:

```
bool search(int* a, int n, int x)
{
  a[n] = x;
  int idx = 0;
  while (a[idx] != x) // n + 1 comparisons in case if value hasn't been found
    ++idx;
  return idx < n; // (n + 2)-th comparison in case if value hasn't been found
}
```

## Solution (not perfect, though)

I can see only one way to cut that extra comparison with this approach: is to use the fact that zero integer value converts to false and any integer value not equal to zero converts to true. Using this the code is going to look like this:

```
bool search(int* a, int n, int x)
{
  a[n] = x;
  int idx = 0;
  while (a[idx] != x) // n + 1 comparisons in case if value hasn't been found
    ++idx;
  return idx - n; // returns 0 only when idx == n, which means that value is not found
}
```

Comment: This is not an exercise question. it has been asked in an interview. I did not get what you are trying to say. can you elaborate it little more? if possible with an example.:-)

and M is always greater than N. (M > N)

Comment: You know, actually I'm wrong :) The provided solution will have N+2 comparisons, not N+1. See updated answer (will not take long).

Comment: Yeah. This is the simple approach. I really did not get this idea at the time of interview for this problem. Anyways, thanks for the solution.:)